# Google script to create all-day calendar entries

Tags: google-apps-script

Apologies if this has been covered but I am trying to write a script for a google form that when completed will send 'events' to my google calendar.  I want these events to be all-day events but the closest I could get to making that work was the below but I still get the time 00:00 on it.. Can anyone help?

```
///this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar settings page of the calendar in question  

var calendarId = "bj8vckkvvhnq4ujr2sb914n03c@group.calendar.google.com";  


//below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)  

var startDtId = 4;  

var endDtId = 5;  

var titleId = 2;  

var descId = 3;  

var formTimeStampId = 1;  


function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {  

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  

   var rows = sheet.getDataRange();  

   var numRows = rows.getNumRows();  

   var values = rows.getValues();  

   var lr = rows.getLastRow();  

   var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr,startDtId,1,1).getValue();  


//set to first hour and minute of the day.  

   startDt.setHours(0);  

   startDt.setMinutes(00);  

   var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr,endDtId,1,1).getValue();  


//set endDt to last hour and minute of the day  

   endDt.setHours(23);  

   endDt.setMinutes(59);  

   var subOn = "Submitted on :"+sheet.getRange(lr,formTimeStampId,1,1).getValue();  

   var desc = "Added by :"+sheet.getRange(lr,descId,1,1).getValue()+"\n"+subOn;  

   var title = sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue() 

     createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc);  

 }​  



   function createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc) {  

   var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);  

   var start = new Date(startDt);  

   var end = new Date(endDt);  

   var loc = '';   


   var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {  

       description : desc,  

       location : loc  

   });  

 };
```

Comment: Format the code of this question please.

Comment: Use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) and step through the code.  We don't know the values or value types being retrieved from the spreadsheet.  In the debugger, it will show the value type.  The debug window should show that the date values are a date type.  I don't understand the point of setting the start time to `00:00`?  Have you tried setting it to 1 minute past midnight?

Answer (score 0):

There is a different function "createAllDayEvent" used to create all day events.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEvent(String,Date,Object)

Comment: Thanks Cameron. I've tried changing it to use the createalldayevent function and I end up with a script error. Not sure if I'm putting it in the right place.

Comment: The only reason I added these start and end times was that otherwise with the date inputs it was treating the end date as midnight and not registering it